# bulk save for RedisOM python bindings

Tags: redis

Fairly new to Redis, Redis Stack, and RedisOM, and was looking into pipelines/workflows for bulk indexing of data when using RedisOM models.

I noticed that redis-om-spring has a [`repo.saveAll()` method](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring/blob/87bbda0d8d9b14a69b17ca1c519d6174d2889124/redis-om-spring/src/test/java/com/redis/om/spring/annotations/bloom/BloomTest.java#L70).  A bit of googling suggests this opens a connection *once*, and reuses that for save operations.  Anecdotal reports show ~1m records indexed in 50 seconds, which would be more than sufficient.

I'm not finding anything similar in the python bindings; am I missing something?  or is this planned?

If not available -- and I wouldn't be surprised if not yet available -- any suggestions on performant ways to index data into Redis when using the Redis Stack + Redis OM?  Many thanks for any suggestions.

**UPDATE:** I didn't realize how new RedisOM was, that I was basically using a "preview" release.  Any thoughts welcomed, but not expecting much at this point!